# When can I use onNext in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, behaviorsubject

If I have

```
let myValue = BehaviorSubject(value: 30)

myValue.subscribe(onNext: {
    print($0)
}, onError: { error in
    print(error)
}, onCompleted: {
    print("Completed")
}, onDisposed: {
    print("Disposed")
    }).disposed(by: bag)

myValue.onNext(33)
myValue.onNext(200)
```

I can add more values with `onNext` as seen above. But if I instead use

```
let myValue2 = BehaviorSubject.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

then then `onNext` doesn't work anymore. Why? Is it because `onNext` only works on `observables` with single values?

Comment: BehaviorSubject(value: 30) - creates BehaviorSubject, BehaviorSubject.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) - creates Observable, observable doesn't have onNext

Comment: Ah, thanks. But why is it called BehaviorSubject if it's an Observable?

Comment: it is still ObservableType, look through the docs

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the file Sequence.swift where the `public static func ObservableType.of(_:)` is defined, you will see that the function returns an Observable, not a BehaviorSubject.

All `ObservableType`s have this function and `BehaviorSubject` is an Observable Type, but it returns the same for all of them.